The CSS linkage to the HTML file in Spring Boot has disappeared
I'm not the first one with this problem here, but nothing I've found on this site has helped me. Maybe someone can explain with my own example where the error is and why the styles and scripts are not loading into the HTML? When I first created and linked the files, the scripts and styles were loading without configuration settings. Then suddenly they stopped (if I'm not mistaken, after a commit to GitHub), even though I made no changes to these files. What is the reason and how can I fix it?
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/styles/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
    }
}

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    private final JWTTokenConfig jwtTokenConfig;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .antMatchers("/register","/host_page", "/login", "/music_files").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/static/**","/background.jpg").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/*", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/personal_office/**").authenticated()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/main").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/free_subscription").hasAnyRole("FREE", "OPTIMAL", "MAXIMUM", "ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/optimal_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "OPTIMAL", "ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/maximum_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/admin_office/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore((Filter) jwtTokenConfig, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Host Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/css/host_page.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class PetMusicStorageApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PetMusicStorageApplication.class, args);
    }
}

enter image description here
Why did the styles and script load initially even without configuration settings, and then the linkage disappeared?
Code after correction
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry 
registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/styles/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/images/images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/");
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/js/script/**")
              
  .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/script/");
    }
}

@Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**", 
"/styles/**", "/images/**", "/js/**");
    }

body {
  background-image: url("/images/background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center -100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
} 

or another style option
body {
  background-image: url("/background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center -100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfig {
private final JWTTokenConfig jwtTokenConfig;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .antMatchers("/register","/host_page", "/login", "/music_files").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/static/**","/images/background.jpg").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/*", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/personal_office/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/main").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/free_subscription").hasAnyRole("FREE", "OPTIMAL", "MAXIMUM", "ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/optimal_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "OPTIMAL", "ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/maximum_subscription").hasAnyRole("MAXIMUM", "ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/admin_office/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore((Filter) jwtTokenConfig, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**", "/styles/**", "/images/**", "/js/**");
}

}

The reason is Spring Security dependency (that you added when it all stopped working) that by default blocks unauthorized access to any static files as well.
In your MvcConfic class just override the following method to allow access to static files:
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/statics/**", "/styles/**");
}


I suggested this approach since you are still using WebMvcConfigurer - you should however consider the new approach of defining it as a Spring Bean instead to easier migrate to latest Spring Version:
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**", "/styles/**", "/images/**", "/js/**");
}


Thank you, it helped with the styles. Could you explain how to unblock images and scripts? What did I do wrong?  enter image description here enter image description here enter image description here enter image description here

Additional information: enter image description here

Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. Also don't add these as comments - edit the question and add code fragments there

Regarding your questions i updated my answer - should be obvious no? you just need to add whatever folder you need to allow to the list that goes into antMatchers

I figured out the scripts before your message. I was just not attentive. But with the images, something is still not working. What could be the reason? I edited the form with the code.

I don't have enough information to answer regarding the images: 1) is the path you used in ResourceHandler correct .addResourceHandler("/images/images/**")? 2) what is html code that is referring to the image 3) and most importantly what is the status code for image not loading the the Requests tab?  Please add answers to these questions to the original question 4) Also what is the complete path starting from the project root to the requested image?

The path is correct. Here is the full path: C:\Users\DELL\IdeaProjects\Pet_Music_Storage\PetMusicStorage\src\main\resources\static\images\background.jpg. This is the background image, and if I understand correctly, it should be automatically loaded through the body selector. Is it possible that a specific command is needed in Spring for the background? Regarding errors: I am receiving a 403 error, but security seems to be configured correctly. Isn't it? I edited the code block.

Resolved. It was necessary to specify a longer path.  background-image: url("/images/images/background.jpg"); Thank you very much for your time, advice, and assistance!

happy it helped:)
